# WebAPI 2, changing output stream from "LimitMemoryStream"

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

So I'm trying to stream content my API into the client, the aim is to get data to the client as quickly as possible. I will be talking to a different endpoint that may be slow to complete the entire request.

The issue im having, is even if I use StreamContent/PushStreamContent, WebAPI seems to buffer whatever I get it, and ignore any calls to flush. This is annoying. I could have data there a client can use, and it could be a long time until the other end returns data, so I would like the client to at least get it.

In my testing, I have added Task.Delay in writing a loop of data out from a stream. Depending on how webapi has chosen to buffer it, it could take a few minutes to return any data, even though data is written to its output stream after a few hundred milliseconds.

It seems to be related that the `HttpResponseMessage` calls `HttpContent.SerializeToStreamAsync` with `LimitMemoryStream`, I believe this is deciding how to buffer the output.

Is there any way in webapi to override this?, eg creating my own implementation that actually responds to flush?.

Comment: I don't think Web API is the best tool to do this, for its architecture and the way it works (specailly the pipeline, and the formatters). I think you wouldn't find such difficulties if you used WCF, much more fitted for this kind of job.

Comment: That seems like a shame, the flow would be akin to watching a video thats being live streamed, which I would've thought webapi would fit into. It all works well apart from this internal buffering that I can't figure out how to override/tweak.

Comment: Web API is not thought for this kind of thing. For me it's not a shame that nailing with a screwdriver is difficutl. I'd use a hammer instead. Why don't you google "web api streaming"? You'll find some examples of streaming with Web API. But I'd google "wcf streaming" or "wcf streaming audio" for a more particular implementation?

Answer (score 1):

I found the kernel of the answer [here](http://blog.cincura.net/233493-httpclient-streaming-upload/).  That post is talking about HttpClient/HttpRequestMessage but I believe the same thing applies for HttpResponseMessage.  You either need to set a content length on the request, or set the TransferEncodingChunked header to true.  If you do neither, then WebAPI *must* buffer the response so that it can compute a length for you.